# How can i use URL Parameters to change where a file is imported from with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application and i am using react-router-dom to fetch the Url parameter that a user enters, eg:

```
localhost:300/Orange
```

I am then able to echo 'Orange' on to the page like this:

```
export  function test() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
function Child() {

  let { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
     {id}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, in my application i am importing a file and i would like the file imported to be the value of the URL parameter,
So if the user visits: `localhost:3000/banana` , the page will import 'banana' like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  loadWeb3,
  loadAccount,
  loadToken,
  loadExchange
} from '../store/banana'
```

or if the user visits `localhost:3000/apple` :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  loadWeb3,
  loadAccount,
  loadToken,
  loadExchange
} from '../store/apple'
```

i think i have to use  `{id}` like this `'../store/{id}'` however i am unsure of where to add the function around the 'import' statement.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you would need to do this? Can you not import your store inside the relevant component that gets switched in the router? i.e. when the apple component loads, import the apple store inside that. etc.

Answer (score 0):

{ id } wont be available outside of that Child function scope.

What you might want to try is...

```
import {
  loadWeb3,
  loadAccount,
  loadToken,
  loadExchange
} from '../store'
```

and export your loadWeb3, loadAccount, loadToken, etc. something like

```
export const loadWeb3 = {
    apple: loadWeb3Apple,
    banana: loadWeb3Banana // <-- this being what you want to export for banana (function/variable/whatever)
}
```

then you can access them like in Child

```
loadWeb3.[id] // this will reference loadWeb3.apple or loadWeb3.banana depending on id
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like that you need [dynamic import](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import).

But since the dynamic import isn't something that's easily achievable using the bundlers (Webpack, Rollup, Parcel...) I suggest you find another strategy for importing.

Maybe you can create a new file that imports all stores and then in the Child resolve the right functions. Example.

*store/fruits.js*

```js
import * as banana from './banana'
import * as apple from './apple'

export default {
  banana,
  apple
}
```

*components/Child.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import fruits from '../store/fruits'

function Child() {
  let { id } = useParams();

  const {
    loadWeb3,
    loadAccount,
    loadToken,
    loadExchange
  } = fruits[id];

  return (
    <div>
     {id}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment, there's probably a better way to handle this kind of problem.

You could have some extra controller logic on top of the functions you want to import, that determines the appropriate store/store functions to use depending on the `id`.

```
const appleStore = {
  loadWeb3:()=>{},
  loadAccount:()=>{},
  loadToken: ()=>{},
  loadExchange: ()=>{}
}

const orangeStore = {
  loadWeb3:()=>{},
  loadAccount:()=>{},
  loadToken: ()=>{},
  loadExchange: ()=>{}
}

export function getStore(id){
  if (id === 'apple'){
     return appleStore;
  }
  else if (id === 'orange'){
     return orangeStore;
  }
  else {
    // return a defaultStore or throw an error
  }
}
```

That may be more stable and would allow you to handle unrecognized path parameters more elegantly.

But in case you still want to go down this route. Here is a quick solution that I have tried that looks to work for me.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function Child(){
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { 
    loadWeb3,
    loadAccount,
    loadToken,
    loadExchange } = require(`../store/${id}.ts`)
  
  return <div>{id}</div>;
}
```